# ssh client takes a long time to respond

Tags: ssh

I have 2 servers, A & B, both running CentOS 5.7.

If I ssh using Putty from Windows 7 to server A or B, the password prompt is quick

But if I ssh from Ubuntu 11.10 to server A, the password prompt takes a long time, almost 2 minutes; while server B password prompt is quick, though not as quick as using Putty.

```
htw@htw-HP-ProBook-4421s:~$ time ssh use@A.biz
user@A.biz's password: 
Connection closed by A.biz

real    2m33.170s

htw@htw-HP-ProBook-4421s:~$ time ssh user@B.biz
user@B.biz's password: 

real    0m1.904s
```

There shouldn't be anything wrong with both servers since ssh-ing from Win 7 is quick. The puzzling bit is logging onto server B is faster than onto server A using Ubuntu. Both servers sshd.conf are already set to `UseDNS=no`

How do I debug this?

Comment: Run `ssh -vvv use@A.biz`. Post the output (obscure IP addresses for privacy), indicating where there's a delay.

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate question, however the answer here seems to be better than the original. Could they be combined?

Answer (score 6):

The most common cause for this is

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. If you are not using this as an authentication method, setting

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

will speed up your ssh client.

You can also change this for just your user by setting up a personal configuration in ~/.ssh/config but if you are the only user on the system, or all users will benefit, then setting it in /etc/ssh/ssh_config is fine.

See `man ssh_config` for more information on setting up your ssh client.